# pandas.Dataframe.loc() and pandas.Dataframe.drop() not working

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am using pandas to create a ranklist. I created a csv file and used pandas to create a Dataframe. When I am slicing the dataframe using iloc method, its working fine, but its showing error with loc method. Similar error is also shown with drop method. When I am dropping the first column "Name", it works fine, but it again doesn't work with the remaining columns.

```
import pandas
#creating CRL
file1 = pandas.read_csv("csvfile_of_ranklist2.csv")
print(file1.index)
print(file1.columns)
file2 = file1.drop("Name",axis=1)
print(file1)
print(file2)
```

It gave the following output:

```
C:\Users\VIVEK PANDYA\Documents\Python programs>E:/python.exe "c:/Users/VIVEK PANDYA/Documents/Python programs/ranklist.py"
RangeIndex(start=0, stop=8, step=1)
Index(['Name', ' Category', ' Maths', ' Physics', ' Chemistry', 'Unnamed: 5'], dtype='object')
              Name  Category   Maths   Physics   Chemistry Unnamed: 5
0     Vivek Pandey        C1      89        78         100        NaN
1    Prateek Singh        C3     100        75          68
2     Yuvraj Singh        C3      88        92          36        NaN
3  Shaiqua Parveen        C2     100        52          32        NaN
4      Sana Afshan        C1      78        85          21        NaN
5    Shabber Islam        C2      89        23          56        NaN
6    Brahma Pandey        C4      78        54          62        NaN
7    Santosh Singh        C1      85        64          92        NaN
   Category   Maths   Physics   Chemistry Unnamed: 5
0        C1      89        78         100        NaN
1        C3     100        75          68
2        C3      88        92          36        NaN
3        C2     100        52          32        NaN
4        C1      78        85          21        NaN
5        C2      89        23          56        NaN
6        C4      78        54          62        NaN
7        C1      85        64          92        NaN
```

However if I try to drop "Category", it produces error:

```
import pandas
#creating CRL
file1 = pandas.read_csv("csvfile_of_ranklist2.csv")
print(file1.index)
print(file1.columns)
file2 = file1.drop("Category",axis=1)
print(file1)
print(file2)

C:\Users\VIVEK PANDYA\Documents\Python programs>E:/python.exe "c:/Users/VIVEK PANDYA/Documents/Python programs/ranklist.py"
RangeIndex(start=0, stop=8, step=1)
Index(['Name', ' Category', ' Maths', ' Physics', ' Chemistry', 'Unnamed: 5'], dtype='object')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\VIVEK PANDYA\Documents\Python programs\ranklist.py", line 8, in <module>
    file2 = file1.drop("Category",axis=1)
  File "E:\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py", line 311, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "E:\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 4906, in drop
    return super().drop(
  File "E:\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 4150, in drop
    obj = obj._drop_axis(labels, axis, level=level, errors=errors)
  File "E:\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 4185, in _drop_axis
    new_axis = axis.drop(labels, errors=errors)
  File "E:\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 6017, in drop
    raise KeyError(f"{labels[mask]} not found in axis")
KeyError: "['Category'] not found in axis"
```

Similarly, if i try to drop the indexes or slice indexes or columns using labels, it produces 'index not found in axis' or 'column not found in axis' error.
I tried looking for any solution in pandas documentation, but I found no solution.
How can this be solved?

Comment: Look at the print statements, `Category` has a leading whitespace

Comment: Also a general point: do not show your actual paths: 'C:\Users\VIVEK PANDYA\Documents\Python programs>E:/python.exe' just edit them to be like 'path_to_my_file'. Just a good practice :) .

Comment: @Pelle Martin Hesketh Thank You. I'll take care of that.

Comment: If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This helps keep the focus on older SO which still don't have answers.

Answer (score 0):

Get column names by `file1.columns`. Copy and use these column names. Your column names probably have whitespaces in the beginning or in the end.

Comment: Got it.  So in the "Name" column there is no whitespace in the beginning, so its working with it, but with the other column names it won't work because of leading whitespace.

Comment: @VivekPandey Exactly.

Comment: Because the "Name" column doesn't have the leading whitespace. Check the outcome of `print(file.columns)` carefully. You'll see that there is a whitespace befor Category, Maths, Physics and Chemistry:  `['Name', ' Category', ' Maths', ' Physics', ' Chemistry', 'Unnamed: 5']`

Answer (score 0):

`' Category'` and most of the other column names have a leading whitespace. It says in the error `KeyError: "['Category'] not found in axis"`, because `'Category'` isn't a columnname.

A simple way to tidy up your column names is:

```
file.columns = [x.strip() for x in file.columns]
```

Now your Pandas Dataframe has columns without the leading whitespace and using `'Category'` does work.

Comment: not all the other column names

Comment: you have a syntax error and `file.columns.str.strip()` exists

Comment: forgot the `=` (`file.columns = [x.strip() for x in file.columns]`). And lots of roads lead to Rome ;-). In this case, performance will not matter if you use `file.columns = [x.strip() for x in file.columns]` or 'file.columns = file.columns.str.strip()`